# Trace gcc linker linking process

Tags: c, gcc, ld

How can I trace the gcc ld linker linking process? I need to see how it link with function from shared objects.

Comment: You should be able to see that from the resulting binary with `nm -D`  or `objdump -T`

Comment: I need to see the process of creating what I can see from the resulting binary using the aforementioned commands.

Comment: What's wrong with `gcc -v`?  That shows you exactly how `gcc` is invoking `ld`.

Comment: @TobySpeight `gcc -v` doesn't show which libraries the link editor actually uses and how it resolves symbols.

Comment: Ah, so the question is about `ld` and not about `gcc`, then?  The tags are a bit misleading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on what you are after, you can pass either `-Wl,--trace` or `-Wl,--cref` to `gcc`, instructing the linker to print additional details about the linking process:

- [`--trace` option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-input-files_002c-displaying)
- [`--cref` option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-cross-reference-table)

If you are interested in a particular symbol, say `SYMBOL`, you could try [`-Wl,--trace-symbol,SYMBOL`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-symbol-tracing) as well.

(This assumes that you are using binutils `ld`, of course.)